# I can only see vertex colors in Vertex Paint mode - otherwise gray

Tags: vertex-colors

I'm using Blender 2.81 beta. I imported a large glTF model which has only vertex colors. (I can see them in other glTF apps like the web viewers.) After the import completes (it takes a while, 7M verts, 14.7M faces, 182 objects) it's all gray. No vertex colors visible -- neither in the viewport, nor EEVEE, nor Cycles.

However, if I select one sub-object and go into Vertex Paint mode, the vertex colors show up on the active object! (If I select more than one, only the active one gets its colors.) So I know they're in there -- they just don't show up. And I can vertex-paint them out. But they just never show up in the render.

Do I need to do something to get vertex colors to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a workaround. These objects don't have any material in the glTF, just the vertex colors. So I created a material on one object, basic Principled BSDF, and as the color input I added Vertex Color node with the color set to `COLOR_0`. Then I linked that material to all the other objects, and it seems to work.

A bit painful, not sure why the importer can't just do that, but it does work for me.

Comment: I am new to Blender and I have the same problem but I couldn't figure it out. Can you give more instructions on how you solved the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's been too long; I don't remember any more details than I wrote above; but that should be the basic plan -- create a material for your object and use Vertex Color as the color input for it.